# how do you skip a request and move to the next requests if the website is not responding? (python)

Tags: python, request

how do you skip a request and move to the next requests if the website is not responding?

```
for website in websites:
  try:
    response = requests.get(website, timeout=5)
  except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the status code of the response.  If it is 200 then you are golden, if it is 404 close then it means the request failed.

```
for website in websites:
    try:
        response = requests.get(website, timeout=5)
    except:
        return
    if resoponse.status_code != 200:
        # .... do something
    else:
         # .... do something else.
```